# Access web project on mac host from Windows parallels

Tags: coldfusion, windows-10, parallels, macos-high-sierra, commandbox

I have found a lot of similar discussion, but non of it really helped.

When I tried to run PHP web project on Mac and access from virtualized Windows, I got correct result on multiple ports.
I think, that this means that I have correct settings in parallels and firewall (I didn't set any port forwarding on parallels and I have set 'shared networking'). Also SQL db from virtualized Windows is accessible on Mac without any issue (in this case, db port is forwarded).

My issue appear when I tried to run Coldfusion project on Commandbox.

My project runnig on localhost:61212 for example.

I tried port forwarding on parallels, from 61212 to 61212 on correct IP address.

Also tried to edit /etc/pf.conf. I add `pass in proto tcp from any to any port 61212` and did `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`.

But because of mentioned PHP experience, maybe I need to correct setup of Commandbox Coldfusion, but I don't have any clue where to do this.

Of course firewall is off on both.

Last think what I tried was install of [Bonjour](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on Windows according to some discussion on other forum.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be run commandbox server on Paralles. When server can running upon shared project file and it could connect to mysql on host, source code could be edited as usual and site could be reload on paralles. Little slow, but all fine.

But it exists better solution.
For case that host ip is 10.211.55.2 and wanted port is 12345.

`box server start host=10.211.55.2 port=12345` [see doc](https://ortus.gitbooks.io/commandbox-documentation/embedded_server/server_port_and_host.html)

Then access from paralles by url `http://10.211.55.2:12345`. Same url is accessible from host.

Answer (score 0):

If port 80 is available on your Mac, you can try to configure CommandBox to start ColdFusion on port 80.

At the `box` prompt (in your app root directory), with the server stopped, type:

`server set web.http.port=80`.

This will create a `server.json` file with the content:

```
{
    "web":{
        "http":{
            "port":"80"
        }
    }
}
```

You can find out more about how to configure CommandBox with the help of a `server.json` file, as described in the docs:
https://ortus.gitbooks.io/commandbox-documentation/content/embedded_server/serverJSON/serverjson.html

Comment: Thank you for good idea. I totally forget to test it on that port. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Even port 80 is closed (according to nmap) commandbox wouldn't to run on that port because 'it is used'. I closed all applications (I don't know if Skype can do somethink like this). Ofcourse I turn off the appache.